# Do vulnerabilities stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, vulnerability

Do vulnerabilities work like resistances, in that they do not stack, or are they handled differently and can be stacked?

For example, if I use a power on an NPC that gives them **vulnerable to radiant 5** until save ends, and then after I use a different power to give them **vulnerable to radiant 3** until end of my next turn, does the NPC now have **vulnerability 8** or **vulnerability 5**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vulnerability follows the same rules as resistance in that they **do not stack if the damage types are the same,** only the highest vulnerability applies.
These rules can be found on page 225-226 of the *Rules Compendium.*

To use your example: because the damage types are the same (radiant), the creature would only have vulnerable 5 to radiant, not vulnerable 8 radiant.

If however the damage types were different, let's say vulnerable 5 radiant and 3 fire, then they would both be applicable. Fire damage would deal 3 extra, radiant damage would deal 5 extra and unlike resistance, both vulnerabilities would still apply if a power dealt both fire and radiant damage.

From page 226 of the *RC:*

> Not cumulative  Vulnerabilities to the same damage type are not cumulative only the highest vulnerability applies. Example: if a creature as vulnerable 5 psychic and then gains vulnerable 10 psychic, it has vulnerable 10 psychic, not vulnerable 15 psychic.

Comment: I added a note at the end expressing what them both being applicable would mean (they still don't stack). I think it would deal the lowest of the two, but my rules compendium is boxed away somewhere. Could you check?

Comment: @doppelgreener that's the case with resistance but doesn't seem to apply to vulnerability.

Comment: Hm. The rule you're quoting doesn't comment on this, did you quote the right one? It says vulnerability counts even if it's for just one of the damage types, but it doesn't say what happens if you take multiple damage types at once and you're vulnerable to each of them.

Comment: @doppelgreener that's true and I wondered about that myself but that's literally all the *RC* has to say about vulnerability against combined damage types. I'd interpret them as both still applying just based on the first line, there's just 2 vulnerabilities to 2 specific (although different) damage types instead of the 1 given in the example. But that's just my interpretation, maybe I should edit the answer to reflect that?

Comment: but for the quote it's just explain that he take more damage.

Comment: i changed the quote to fit more with the example its from the page 226 and from the section vulnerability of the RC

Comment: +1, I was skeptical about both vulnerabilities applying to a combined damage type, but I've reviewed the RC and agree with your conclusions.